# Beating The Demon Stink (Against the Cockroaches Part 2)

Tags: loot-and-legends

I have been trying all sorts of strategies on this level, and I haven't come up with something that works yet.  This is the level where Morvin the Malod... is sitting on one of the star squares, chilling out and racking up a star each round.  There are 6 cockroaches on the field as well.

I have tried to defeat the cockroaches quickly and then go after Morvin, but by the time I get there, I run out of turns and he gets enough stars to win.  The closest I have come is one time where my main character had a triple kill card at the right time, and I was able to kill 3 cockroaches at the same time.

I have tried to just move to him as quickly as possible, but usually one or two of my players dies before I get there.  I have also tried to equip anything that will give me more movement, but I seem to do even worse.

Cleanse doesn't help because Morvin just puts his stink card back on my player after it has been removed.  It seems like he has an unreasonable number of cards in his hand, because he attacks a lot.  It also doesn't help that I can't use any cards to move him off of the square, because he always uses Immobility.

Does anyone out there have a good strategy for getting past this level?  It's driving me crazy, and I don't want to buy pizza.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have two people left: the wizard elf and the dwarf, or the wizard elf and the other one.

The wizard elf should have the acid pool card equipped, and make sure you are close to Morvin to use the acid pool terrain card.

Comment: Make sure the wizard elf has the acid pool card equipped.

Comment: And make sure you are close to morvin to use the acid pool terrain card

Comment: you should edit your post to add additional information instead of commenting it